error in url after switching from VB5 to XF 2.3
after importing vb5 (to XF 2.3.3) all went ok except for some errors in a few pages.
the page in the main has a thread that I can't view, I get "The requested page could not be found." while the thread is there!!
and if I go to the forum where the thread belongs I can view it with no issue
the main URL that gives me an error is The requested page could not be found.
and the other one that works ok is the same but without "post-0"
how can I fix the "post-0" at the end of the url in .htaccess ?
I see the url shown at the main board with "post-0" at the end, which doesnt work.
need to fix that in .htaccess

By VB5 do you mean Visual Basic 5 from the 1990s?  Or something else?

Open your website's .htaccess file and
add these lines:
CopyRewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/post-0/?$ /$1 [R=301,L]

Save the .htaccess file
Upload it back to your server
Clear your browser cache and XenForo cache

Try, fixing the URL structure you provided:
https://domain.tld/index.php?threads/dhkr-mn-dhkriat-aiam-altful.65934/post-0

This uses query parameters rather than a clean URL. The previous rewrite rule may not work for this format.

Thanks for the reply.. actually I contacted XF support, and the problem turned out to be with the built-in "rebuild cash." I used it, and that fixed it

I contacted XF support, and the problem turned out to be with the built-in "rebuild cash." I used it, and that fixed it
